# Cómo verificar posiciones de caracteres en string a través de un patrón con Expresiones Regulares?

Tags: javascript, regex

Saludos a toda la comunidad, necesito hacer lo siguiente y quisiera saber si es posible hacerlo con expresiones regulares:

Tengo un string de una longitud de 25 caracteres compuestos por 0 y 1:
ejemplo: `0010101110110101010011011`

Y tengo varios patrones los cuales son condiciones para ganar:
ejemplo

Patrón 1: `1111110001100011000111111`

Patrón 2: `1111110000000000000111111`

Lo que quiero hacer es buscar la manera de verificar si las posiciones de los `1` dados en los patrones coinciden en el string, independientemente de que el string tenga otros `1` en posiciones donde el patron tiene `0`.

**Ejemplos:**

Dado el string: `1111110011101111010111111`,
si hacemos un match con el patrón 1: `1111110001100011000111111` el resultado sería **true**, ya que las posiciones de los 1 del string coinciden con los del patrón.
**111111**001**11**011**11**010**111111**.

Ejemplo 2:
Dado el string `1101110011101111010111111`, si lo comparamos con los 2 patrones anteriormente dados, el resultado sería **false** ya que las posiciones de los `1` no coinciden.

Estoy usando Node.js pero también puedo usar Python, si pueden ayudarme se los agradezco.

Comment: Al final de la pregunta hice la aclaratoria que estoy usando Nodejs (javascript), pero también me sirve en Python, por supuesto que las etiquetas están relacionadas con la pregunta.

Comment: Se especifico con la pregunta, solo indica un lenguaje, removi python ya que hiciste más énfasis en javascript. Por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas expresiones regulares. Nota que estás trabajando con números binarios. Tienes un patrón y tienes una entrada. Lo único que debes hacer es realizar un AND entre el patrón y de la cadena. Si el resultado del AND es igual al patrón, entonces los unos coinciden. Si no es igual al patrón, entonces los unos no coinciden. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
const pattern = Number.parseInt('1111110001100011000111111', 2);
const input = Number.parseInt('1111110011101111010111111', 2);

const result = (input & pattern) === pattern;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jaime, considero que es la respuesta que mejor se adapta a mis necesidades!

Answer (score 0):

En Javascript:

```
const patronOne = '1111110001100011000111111';
const patronTwo = '1111110000000000000111111';

const checkPatron = (patron, value) => {
  
  let check = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    if(value[i] == 0) {
      if(patron[i] == 1)
      check = false;
    }
  }
  return check;
}

console.log(checkPatron(patronOne, '1111110011101111010111111'));
console.log(checkPatron(patronOne, '1101110011101111010111111'));
```

Donde la función checkPatron recibe 2 parámetros, patrón y valor a evaluar. Dentro de esta se recorre el valor (se transforma en un array) y se verifica si donde hay un 0, en el patrón existe un 1, entonces retornaría un false.

Comment: Está bastante interesante tu implementación Eduardo, fíjate que pensando en las posibles soluciones no me había imaginado esta.

Answer (score -1):

Espero que te ayude!

```
#String es la cadena que quieres verificar
#Patron es la condicion ganadora

def match(string, patron):

    #Voy a recorrer la cadena patron y guardar los index donde el valor sea "1"
    posiciones = []

    for i in range(len(patron)):
        if patron[i] == "1":
            posiciones.append(i)

    #Voy a recorrer la cadena "string" pero solo en los index importantes (donde era 1 en la cadena patron)
    #Y voy a contar las veces que coincidan.
    contador = 0
    for i in posiciones:
        if string[i] == "1":
            contador = contador + 1

    #Para que sea True basta que el contador sea igual a la cantidad de valores "1" que habían en la cadena "patron"
    if contador == len(posiciones):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Por favor debes explicar lo que hiciste.

Comment: Esta respuesta no sirve a nadie más que a ti. Por valor considera agregar una buena explicación. Lee [answer]

Comment: Gracias Jorge, aprecio mucho tu respuesta, logré implementar esta función en JS, sin embargo la respuesta que me dio Jaime ha sido bastante concreta y correcta, ayuda mucho a mi codigo.